# Oracle Sql Check Constraint != other table

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to include a check constraint on a table between the primary key of the latter and the primary key of another table and insert! = Between the two, how can i do it?
I've been tempted like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RESPONSABILE(
    ID_RESP             CHAR(10)        REFERENCES  UTENTE(ID_USER) PRIMARY KEY,
    CODICE_FISCALE      VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    NOME                VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
    COGNOME             VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  CK_FI   CHECK           (REGEXP_LIKE(CODICE_FISCALE,'^[A-Z]{6}[\d+]{2}[ABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[\d+]{2}([A-Z]{1}[\d+]{3})[A-Z]{1}$','I')),
    CONSTRAINT  CK_RE   CHECK           (ID_RESP != (ID_PR) REFERENCES PR(ID_PR) AND ID_RESP != (ID_CLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTE(ID_CLIENTE))
);
```

But I have not had any positive results

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data and (2) an explanation of what you want the constraint to check for.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/q/21098932/458741 what you're after?

Comment: From the [definition](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php) of a constraint itself, the scope is limited to one table. So whatever you're trying to do will have to be with some other approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from the text of your syntactically incorrect check constraint, that you want to enforce a multi-table check constraint. The only way to do this in Oracle (and maybe any RDBMS) is with a trigger. You cannot reference multiple tables in a check constraint.

However, depending upon your Oracle version, and according to [the Oracle constraint documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180), you might be able to define a rather complex foreign key constraint as this implies:

> You cannot define a foreign key constraint in a CREATE TABLE statement that contains an AS subquery clause. Instead, you must create the table without the constraint and then add it later with an ALTER TABLE statement

Answer (score 0):

If your primary keys are numbers which are obtained from sequences, the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to get the ID numbers for both tables from the same sequence. If you do it this way you're guaranteed that they won't duplicate each other, and you eliminate the need for a bunch of expensive logic to verify this condition.

Best of luck.

Comment: The tables take id from the mother entity, so I would need to put this constraints, so I can use the script to populate the database